# How to setup heartbeat for IP fail over on SSH failure

Tags: redhat, high-availability, heartbeat

I wonder if anyone can help me, I am trying to setup heartbeat on a redhat 5 to failover an IP address when ssh stops responding on a server. So basically you ssh to a VIP and then get put through which ever server has the floating ip.

```
                        192.168.0.100
                               |
                               |
/------------------------\     |     /------------------------\
| Server 01              |     |     | Server 02              |
| eth0 - 192.168.0.1     |-----/     | eth0 - 192.168.0.2     |
| eth0:0 - 192.168.0.100 |           | eth0:0 - down          |
\------------------------/           \------------------------/
```

if ssh stops responding i want eth0:0 to be brought up on the second machine to allow ssh connections to carry on being served.

I have tried to follow some documents I have found online so here is my current configuration:

ha.cf

```
bcast eth0
keepalive 2
warntime 10
deadtime 30
initdead 120
udpport 694
auto_failback off
node vm-bal01
node vm-bal02
debugfile /var/log/ha-debug
logfile /var/log/ha-log
```

authkeys

```
auth 1
1 sha1 sshhhsecret1234
```

haresources

```
server01 192.168.0.100/24/eth0:0/192.168.0.255
```

Hope someone can help as this is driving me nuts...

Answer (score 0):

Write a monitoring-method for SSH. If it fails issue a `hb_standby all`.